# Time series/Regression question.

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to figure out what variables most significantly affect the download rate of my app. Right now I have a data frame with a column for dates, downloads per day, payouts per day, and a few more other variables that correspond to the date column.

This may be impossible but I'm looking for some way to be able to predict how many downloads I will have based on the values of the factors I have.

Comment: if you explain your data and question more, I have a good answer for you.

Comment: Ok yeah! So basically I have data on about 1600 days this app was running. Every day I have the number of times we "paid out" a user. I also have some other info per day like the number of completed and incomplete tasks. The amount users earned per day. Let me know if you've got more questions!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is find the correlation of the features to find which are more correlated and eliminate any feature (not recommended) which has very low correlation. Or you can apply random forest to find the feature importance and then apply linear regression to find the number of downloads.

Comment: Yes I've tried this, but I was wondering if it was possible to see the relationship between an increase in one and the downloads going up that day or the next day.

Comment: Just doing a simple regression I would only see the relationship between the same day relationship. Also, I wasn't sure if this would violate some of the assumptions due to autocorrelation or something like that. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

This task can be down by variable selection methods. I suggest dynamic regression and autocorrelated residuals (DREGAR). To explain more, the model is like,

\begin{align}
& y_t=\sum_{i=1}^{p} \phi_i y_{t-i} + x'_t \beta +\epsilon_t\\
& \epsilon_t = \sum_{j=1}^{q}\theta_j\epsilon_{t-j} +e_t
\end{align}
where $e_t\sim \,i.i.d \,\,N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $x$ can contain many covariates. Now if you use an $l_1$ penalized likelihood to estimating the parameters, you get a set of (selected) covariates in $x$ and  some (selected) orders for AR term. This is a time-dependent variable selection method. Fortunately, it is implemented in the R package `DREGAR` [See here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DREGAR/DREGAR.pdf) that you can use it.

Update: from your comment, you have 1600 points that is enough for removing bias in this model.

Comment: @b-rowan please vote the answers up/down if you have got your answers. Please do not leave your question without feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building an ARIMA model, incorporating the additional variables as leading indicators?  In this exercise you would build a model that fits your purposes/criteria and optimizes over AIC (my preference) or SIC/BIC.  You can then use the model to forecast expected downloads per day.  Assuming you do use lagged versions of the other variables you have (referenced above as leading indicators), you will be able to quantify the degree to which these variables drive the downloads.

All of this is easily doable in R.  I would look in to the 'forecast' package.